# How to make authentication required to install updates?

Tags: update-manager, password

Ubuntu's new policy dictates that updates to already installed applications don't require password when doing it from Update Manager (Synaptic and apt-get still require password). Also, I would like to prevent the Update Manager to pop-up, it should only run when I invoke it. Thanks.

Comment: You can get the update manager to ask you for updates by going to Software Sources. Under the Updates tab, change the Automatically Check for Updates value to "Never".

Comment: @KrisHarper I am running 12.04. Where do I have to make change? "Software Sources", where are they?

Comment: @kamyogi I can't check right now, but Software Sources should either be available in the Dash, or in one of the menus in the Software Center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the 'update packages without admin auth'

```
gksudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
```

The section in question is this

```
[Update already installed software]
Identity=unix-group:admin
Action=org.debian.apt.upgrade-packages
ResultActive=yes
```

Probably the easiest & maybe best solution is to just remove the whole section.

If desired you could leave & try setting the ResultActive=yes to this

ResultActive=auth_admin_keep

If I wanted this I'd just remove the section, then the action should fallback to the default in /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.debian.apt.policy which is to require auth per use.

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding my id to the `sudo` group solved the problem.
My `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla` has `admin` and `sudo` as authorized groups, but `sudo` had only an user defined during installation, and `admin` group was not defined. I would bet on `adm` there. Perhaps the name `admin` has gotten into the polkit file because someone has overlooked some configuration  changes in the history of Ubuntu (see [What is the difference between the groups "adm" and "admin"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612751/what-is-the-difference-between-the-groups-adm-and-admin))?

An original section of the file from my LTS 20.04.4:

```
[Update already installed software]
Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
Action=org.debian.apt.upgrade-packages
ResultActive=auth_admin_keep
```